# CSS issue center and 'max-width' for an image in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a basic image thumb, that properly works in Firefox/Chrome but doesn't work in IE11.

The image `max-width` is not respected and goes at big as it is.

```css
.thumb {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 0/0 a;
    height: 4.5rem;
    width: 4.5rem;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
    border-radius: 0.1875rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px #BDBDBD;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.thumb img { 
   display: inline-block;
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x90">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: could you share screenshots, I couldn't find any issue in IE11

Comment: @Kikkuz, screenshot attached, also changed the placeholder image, please recheck

Comment: it is not, is my default Windows 7, IE11; the initial placeholder was squared, and was almost ok, I changed the placeholder where width is much bigger than height; the screenshot is the question in IE11

Comment: now able to reproduce the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the issue in IE11, you can add `flex: 1` to the `img` element - see demo below:

```css
.thumb {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 0/0 a;
    height: 4.5rem;
    width: 4.5rem;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
    border-radius: 0.1875rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px #BDBDBD;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.thumb img { 
   display: inline-block;
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    flex: 1; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x90">
</div>
```

Comment: Why use flex when you don't need to? Especially on IE.

Comment: its a flex *item* right, so its fine to use `flex: 1`... :)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding: `min-width:1px;` to your image. It's a known bug of IE.

```css
.thumb {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 0/0 a;
    height: 4.5rem;
    width: 4.5rem;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
    border-radius: 0.1875rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px #BDBDBD;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.thumb img { 
   display: inline-block;
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    min-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x90">
</div>
```